# How do I install a font using NSIS?

Tags: fonts, nsis

I have been trying to build an installer in NSIS that installs a font file. Here's my main installer script:

```
!include FontName.nsh
!include FontReg.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh

RequestExecutionLevel admin
InstallDir $DESKTOP

Name "Orange Juice"
OutFile fonttest.exe

Section "install"

    StrCpy $FONT_DIR $FONTS
    !insertmacro InstallTTFFont "orangejuice.ttf"
    DetailPrint "Installing Orange Juice Font..."
    SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_FONTCHANGE} 0 0 /TIMEOUT=5000

SectionEnd
```

I got the file FontReg.nsh [from here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Register_Fonts) and copied it verbatim into my `Program Files\NSIS\Include` folder. I got the file FontName.nsh (along with the corresponding DLL file) [from here](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/FontName_plug-in) and copied those verbatim. Yet... when I run this script, the font doesn't get installed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- the `FontReg.nsh` defines its proper **variable** to get the font installation directory while you are defining a **constant** with the same name that does not what you think, also you can use directly the `$FONTS` variable that points to the system font directory
- You need to signal the addition of a new font to the system via a broadcast of the `WM_FONTCHANGE` message

Try the following: Delete your `!define FONT_DIR` line and change your section with

```
StrCpy $FONT_DIR $FONTS
!insertmacro InstallTTFFont "orangejuice.ttf"
SendMessage ${HWND_BROADCAST} ${WM_FONTCHANGE} 0 0 /TIMEOUT=5000
```

Comment: Alright, I've updated my original question based on your response here. What you now see above is a verbatim copy of what I'm trying to run; however it *still doesn't work.* What am I still missing?

Comment: Actually, disregard that comment. I had done something wrong, and the above code is now working flawlessly. Thank you!